# No source file detected in flutter easy_localiztion:generate command

Tags: flutter, path, flutter-easy-localization

So, I am trying to run this command in terminal of Android studio:

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart -S assets\translations\ru.json
```

And the path is 100% correct, but for some reason, `the Source path does not exist`. I've checked thousand times, it's all the same :/

I've tried to reload the project, write --source-dir instead of s, write the path different ways:

```
-S ./assets/translations/ru.json
-s assets/translations/
-s assets/translations
```

Nothing changed
Help please!!1!

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to right it:

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart --source-dir ./assets/translations
```